# Developing on SSMS 2016 for SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm developing for a database that's running on SQL Server 2008 R2. Is there any reason I can't develop on SSMS 2016 and deploy those scripts onto production? Or do I have to use SSMS 2008 R2 for development as well?

Comment: A database *doesn't run on SSMS* - SSMS is the GUI frontend tool, it's not the database engine that runs anything. But you should be able to use SSMS 2016 against a SQL Server 2008 R2 database - no problem. If your database compatibility level is set to **105** (for SQL Server 2008 R2), you cannot use any new features - so you should be save.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The main reason I want to use a newer version of ssms is for plugin compatibility. Hopefully the plugins are only dependant on the ssms not the database engine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS is typically backward compatible.

If you are working in a query editor window, the yellow ribbon at the bottom displays your connection status and the SQL Server version number you are connected to. SQL Server 2008 R2 will be version 10.5. When you run the sql script, the features available are based on that version of sql server you are connected to. This is regardless of plugins and add-ons.

[image]